# r User-Defined Function Arguments - what can be defined as the argument?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, arguments, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write R functions that do similar tasks as macros in SAS, such as

1. process variables
2. name a new variable
3. name a new data frame

I've tried some basic functions using the built-in df "iris" and dplyr as pasted below.

Function f3 and f4 try to take in a variable name and process it. the error messages are "Error: object 'Species' not found " and "In mean.default(var) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA".

Function f5 and f6 try to name a new variable or a new df. Once running the function the new variable or df was named after the argument name.

f7 tried to name part of the variable using the function.

```
library(dplyr)

data(iris)
view(iris)

### Char Variable
f3 <- function(var){
      iris %>% filter(var == "setosa")
}
f3(Species)

f4 <- function(var){
      iris %>% summarise(
            avg = mean(var)
      )
}
f4("Sepal.Length")

### Variable Name
f5 <- function(name){
      iris %>% 
            mutate(name = 1)
}
f5("newname")

### df Name
f6 <- function(dfname){
      dfname <- iris 
}
f6("newdf")

f7 <- function(name){
      test <- iris %>% 
            mutate(
                  v_name = 1
            )
}
f7("1")
```

Comment: If you are assigning a new objectin  global  env, use `assign(dfname, iris, envir = .GlobalEnv)`  in `f6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tidyverse`,if we pass unquoted, it can be converted to quosure (`rlang::enquo`) and evaluate (`!!`), which is done with `{{}}` curly-curly operator

```
f3 <- function(var){
  iris %>%
       filter({{var}} == "setosa")
 }
f3(Species)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#...
```

`f4` also can be done with the same for unquoted

```
f4 <- function(var){
  iris %>% 
      summarise(
        avg = mean({{var}})
      )
   }

f4(Sepal.Length)
#     avg
#1 5.843333
```

If the intention is to pass either quoted or unquoted, convert to symbol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
 f4 <- function(var){
  iris %>% 
    summarise(
        avg = mean(!! rlang::ensym(var))
   )
 }
 f4(Sepal.Length)
 #       avg
 #1 5.843333
 f4("Sepal.Length")
 #     avg
 #1 5.843333
```

---

For `f7`, we can use `:=`

```
library(stringr)
f7 <- function(name){
  iris %>% 
        mutate(
              !!str_c("v_", name) := 1
        )
 }

f7("1")
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species v_1
#1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa   1
#2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa   1
#3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa   1
#4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa   1
#...
```

Or with `f5`

```
f5 <- function(name){
  iris %>% 
        mutate(!! name := 1)
 }
f5("newname")
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species newname
#1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa       1
#2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa       1
#3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa       1
#4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa       1
# ..
```

NOTE: If we do `<-` as the last return statement, it would  need to be either assigned to an object or wrap with `()` to print the output i.e. `(f5("newname"))`

`f6` is `assign`ing an object and this can be done with `assign`

```
f6 <- function(dfname){
   assign(dfname, value = iris, envir = .GlobalEnv) 
 }
f6("newdf")
head(newdf, 2)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Thank you! f3 and f4 worked perfectly! But the curly-curly operator doesn't work for the rest of the functions.